# How can I read the logExtFileFlags from the "Default" site?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, iis-7

I am attempting to read IIS 7 configuration data remotely, specifically the logExtFileFlags from the Default site.  When I look at the applicationHost.config on the remote server, I see the information in question:

```
<system.applicationHost>
    <sites>
        <site name="Default" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <logFile logExtFileFlags="Date, Time, ClientIP, UserName, SeverIP, Method, UriStem, URIQuery, HttpStatus, TimeTaken, ServerPort, UserAgent, HttpSubStatus" enabled="true" />
        </site>
      </sites>
</system.applicationHost>
```

I am trying to use ServerManager to read the info remotely.  I've been successful on other parameter that I have read, but they were in the system.webServer section of the applicationHost.config file. I have the code set up as follows:

```
ServerManager manager = ServerManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
var allSites = manager.Sites
foreach (Site currentSite in allSites) 
{
    siteName = currentSite.Name;

    // I only have the "Default" site on the server in question but other servers may have more than one.
    ConfigurationSection  sitesSection =  config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites",siteName);
}
```

The final line does not work.  In fact, it does not compile.  It is just there to sort of give you the idea of what I'm trying to do.  I also realize that there would be additional lines to parse the logFile tags.  Upon further research, I came across the following:

```
ConfigurationSection sitesSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites");
ConfigurationElementCollection sitesCollection = sitesSection.GetCollection();

ConfigurationElement siteElement = FindElement(sitesCollection, "site", "name", @"Default");
```

This seemed like what I wanted to do.  When I typed it in, FindElement was not a valid method for ConfigurationElement.  I'm stumped at this point.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I would also be interested in how to decipher those flags once I can get to the object correctly.  It might be obvious once I get to that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement the `FindElement` method yourself. Have a look at the C# code on this [iis.net page](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/logfile)

The `logExtFileFlags` property will be a string will comma separated values, you can use a string split or linq to turn that into a collection of strings.

Comment: @TomK - In that case you should accept the answer as solving your problem.